# Sublime text, indentation, and python code going bananas

Tags: python, pandas, sublimetext3, indentation

I just had a very weird problem. I am working on some Python 2.7 script and editing it in Sublime 3.

Now, the script run but seemed to behave "illogically", by which I mean that it was not following my logic. For example, sometimes it was not going into an if/else statement.

**EDIT:**

I was able after some time to do something easy to reproduce. Look at the screenshot below and notice the indentation screw up at line 11. Please of course don't mind too much the logic of the code (there is none), it is just to show my point.

[image]

If I run from terminal the way it is I get the output

```
new key
new key
new key
new key
new key
Value already exists
```

and you can see there are less print statements than there are supposed to be. If I fix the indentation keeping it consistent with all tabs for example, I get the output I would expect:

```
new key
new key
Value already exists
Value already exists
new key
new key
Value already exists
Value already exists
new key
{1: [1], 2: [2], 3: [3], 4: [4], 9: [9]}
```

So basically the question is. Is this some sort of bug? Why does the code produce that "illogical" output instead of throwing some kind of indentation error?

**Original post:**

I'll give an example. Suppose I have something like a pandas data frame df on which at some point I'm looping on the rows.

```
d = {}    
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    base = row['base']
    s1 = row['string_1']
    s2 = row['string_2']

    if base not in d:
        d[base] = [sorted([s1,s2])]
        # do something
    else:
        if sorted([s1,s2]) not in d[base]:
            d[base].append(sorted([s1,s2]))
            # do something
        else:
           pass
```

Now, basically it seems that when I run the script sometimes (have no idea based on what) it skipped the if/else statement all together as if it wasn't there. Again, the script was running but was not respecting the logic written in the code. I checked manually many times without being able to make any sense of it.

After a while, I remembered that something similar had happened some time ago and I simply clicked on the lower right corner on Sublime to "Convert indentation to tabs". This seemed to fix the problem. (I probably had copied and pasted a line from a different editor at some point).

What's bugging me is that I really have no idea what was going on. If there was some indentation problem I would expect an error, not the code to run without apparent logic. This was a real pain to debug.

Has anyone else experienced the same and know what this is due to?

Comment: Can you provide some data which gives us a *reproducible* example of the issue you are facing?

Comment: @jpp I have been thinking about how to do this. I had to run now I can try to provide something better tomorrow. It is difficult tho because the wrong indentation is not something I know how to put in a snippet here.